# Unable to display data from remote server using MVVM architecture in android

Tags: java, json, android-studio, android-volley, android-mvvm

I am not able to parse json data from remote server. I am using MVVM architecture and volley library to parse json data. I tried to debug and the message says "An attempt to invoke virtual method has been made on a null object reference". 
I thought that the problem is due to LiveData class, so i removed it. Then, also it's not working. Please, also tell how to use LiveData class.

**BikesRepository.java**

```
package com.example.osama.dashbike.Repository;

import android.content.Context;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.example.osama.dashbike.Models.BikesInfo;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class BikesRepository {
    Context context;
    MutableLiveData<ArrayList<BikesInfo>> mutableLiveData;
    ArrayList<BikesInfo> arrayList;
    Listener mListener;
    String json_url = "http://491ab6f9.ngrok.io/api/note/";

public BikesRepository(Context context, Listener listener){
    this.context = context;
   mListener = listener;
}
public /*LiveData<ArrayList<BikesInfo>*/void getArrayList(){

    mutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, json_url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    JSONArray jsonArray ;
                    try {
                        jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("objects");
                        int i;
                        for (i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                            String c = jsonObject.getString("image");
                            String a = jsonObject.getString("title");
                            String b = jsonObject.getString("body");
                            BikesInfo bikesinfo = new BikesInfo(a,b,c);
                            arrayList.add(bikesinfo);
                            //mutableLiveData.postValue(arrayList);

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    // if listener has been set, send data
                    if (mListener != null){
                        mListener.onDataReceived(arrayList/*mutableLiveData*/);
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // if listener has been set, send error
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onError(error.networkResponse.statusCode);
            }

        }
    });
    Singleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
    //return arrayList;
    //return mutableLiveData;
}
}
```

**BikesViewModel.java**

```
package com.example.osama.dashbike.ViewModels;

import android.app.Application;
import android.arch.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel;
import android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData;
import android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import com.example.osama.dashbike.ApplicatonContext;
import com.example.osama.dashbike.Models.BikesInfo;
import com.example.osama.dashbike.Repository.BikesRepository;
import com.example.osama.dashbike.Repository.Listener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BikesViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    BikesRepository bikesRepository;
    ArrayList<BikesInfo> bikesinfolistobservable;
    //LiveData<ArrayList<BikesInfo>> bikesinfolistobservable;

    public BikesViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        bikesRepository = new BikesRepository(application, new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataReceived(/*MutableLiveData<*/ArrayList<BikesInfo> mutableLiveData) {
                bikesinfolistobservable = mutableLiveData;


            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int error) {

            }
        });
        bikesRepository.getArrayList();

    }

    public /*LiveData<*/ArrayList<BikesInfo> getbikesinfolistobservable(){

        return bikesinfolistobservable;
    }

}
```

**BikesInfo.java**

```
package com.example.osama.dashbike.Models;

public class BikesInfo {
    private String txt1,txt2;
    private String imageurl;
    public BikesInfo(String txt1, String txt2, String imageurl){
        this.setTxt1(txt1);
        this.setTxt2(txt2);
        this.setImageUrl(imageurl);
    }

    public String getTxt1() {
        return txt1;
    }

    public void setTxt1(String txt1) {
        this.txt1 = txt1;
    }

    public String getTxt2() {
        return txt2;
    }

    public void setTxt2(String txt2) {
        this.txt2 = txt2;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageurl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageurl) {
        this.imageurl = imageurl;
    }
}
```

**BikesListAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.osama.dashbike.Views.Adapters;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;
import com.example.osama.dashbike.ApplicatonContext;
import com.example.osama.dashbike.Models.BikesInfo;
import com.example.osama.dashbike.R;
import com.example.osama.dashbike.Repository.Singleton;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BikesListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BikesListAdapter.BikesListHolder> {

    ArrayList<BikesInfo> arrayList1;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public BikesListAdapter(ArrayList<BikesInfo> arrayList){
        this.arrayList1 = arrayList;

        //very costly method i.e. slow performance. Modify it.
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public BikesListHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bikes, viewGroup, false);
        BikesListHolder bikesListHolder = new BikesListHolder(view);
        return bikesListHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BikesListHolder thugHolder, int i) {

        thugHolder.text.setText(arrayList1.get(i).getTxt1());
        thugHolder.text2.setText(arrayList1.get(i).getTxt2());
        imageLoader = Singleton.getInstance(ApplicatonContext.getAppContext()).getmImageLoader();
      thugHolder.image.setImageUrl(arrayList1.get(i).getImageUrl(),imageLoader);


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList1.size();
    }

    public class BikesListHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView text,text2;
        NetworkImageView image;
        public BikesListHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            text2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.osama.dashbike.Views.ui;

import android.arch.lifecycle.Observer;
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import com.example.osama.dashbike.ApplicatonContext;
import com.example.osama.dashbike.Models.BikesInfo;
import com.example.osama.dashbike.R;
import com.example.osama.dashbike.Repository.BikesRepository;
import com.example.osama.dashbike.ViewModels.BikesViewModel;
import com.example.osama.dashbike.Views.Adapters.BikesListAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    BikesViewModel bikesViewModel;
    BikesListAdapter bikesListAdapter;
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bikes_recycler);//activity_main);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        bikesViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BikesViewModel.class);
        bikesListAdapter = new BikesListAdapter(bikesViewModel.getbikesinfolistobservable());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(bikesListAdapter);
                       // observeViewModel(bikesViewModel);
      //  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
       // fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.bikes_fragment_frame, new BikesFragment());
       // fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
   /* private void observeViewModel (BikesViewModel bikesViewModel){
        bikesViewModel.getbikesinfolistobservable().observe(this, new Observer<ArrayList<BikesInfo>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable ArrayList<BikesInfo> bikesInfo) {
                if (bikesInfo != null) {
                    bikesListAdapter = new BikesListAdapter(bikesInfo);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(bikesListAdapter);
                }
            }
        });
    } */
}
```

**Edit:**
**Listener.java**

```
package com.example.osama.dashbike.Repository;

import android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import com.example.osama.dashbike.Models.BikesInfo;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public interface Listener {
    void onDataReceived(/*MutableLiveData<*/ArrayList<BikesInfo> mutableLiveData);
    void onError(int error);
}
```

**Singleton.java**

```
package com.example.osama.dashbike.Repository;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class Singleton {
    private static Singleton mInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    private static Context mCtx;

    private Singleton(Context context){
        mCtx = context;
        mRequestQueue =getRequestQueue();

                mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue,
                        new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                    private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                            cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);
                            @Override
                            public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                                return cache.get(url);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {

                                cache.put(url, bitmap);
                            }
                        });
    }

    public static synchronized Singleton getInstance(Context context){
        if (mInstance == null){
            mInstance = new Singleton(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }
    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue(){
        if (mRequestQueue == null){
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }
    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> request){
        getRequestQueue().add(request);
    }
    public ImageLoader getmImageLoader(){
        return mImageLoader;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think it is the same as your previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53710429/10159898). You don't know when your data has really been retrieved. I'm not aware of the MVP Clean Architecture but, to my mind, you don't use the callback of the listener

Comment: @Bruno, Sorry that i was not able to tell you properly. Actually i have used the listener.java class but not included in the question for the sake of brevity. But i have now edited my question to avoid any confusion. Despite of using listener, my program is not working. I think there might be some problem in viewmodel class, not sure. Thank you for your response btw.